# Drawing a line between moving objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to draw a line between two moving vertices. The vertex's drawing is stored in a variable called `object`, which has a `position`, which is a `THREE.Vector3`.

The line is created thusly:

```
var Line = function(scene, source, target){
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.dynamic = true;
  geometry.vertices.push(source.object.position);
  geometry.vertices.push(target.object.position);
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
  var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

  scene.add(line);
  return line;
};
```

..., where source and target are vertices and the vertices get updated via:

```
vertex.object.position.add(vertex.velocity);
```

Now, I assigned the `source.object.position` and `target.object.position` to the `line.geometry.vertices[0]` and `line.geometry.vertices[1]` because I wanted one to update with the other. But instead, the vertex positions vary wildly from the line positions. The vertices are where they are, but the lines don't connect to the vertices.

How can I make the lines move with the vertices?

Comment: how would this look with BufferGeometry? Since Geometry was removed from Three.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your animation loop you have to set `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true`. Because every time after rendering it becomes `false`. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/4j4euqtv/) example

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. I do have line.verticesNeedUpdate = true; but the lines are still all over the place. I also avoided assigning anything to the position vector that could leave an old reference.

Comment: `.verticesNeedUpdate` is a property of `THREE.Geometry()`, not of a `THREE.Line()` object. Did you have a look at my jsfiddle example?

Comment: Sorry, yes. That's what I meant: line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate. I'm studying your jsfiddle example. It works like a charm, I'm about to see if I can recreate it in my code.